# Como gravar sessões no browser

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, login, cookies

Como gravar sessões no browser com php.

Actualmente tenho um sistema de login, e valida sempre os `[$_SESSIONS]` existentes no browser, mas sempre que fecho e abro novamente o browser, o login já não existe.

Qual a melhor forma para guardar os dados no browser.

- Será util usar COOKIES?
- Devo guardar sessões em Base de Dados?

Qual a melhor forma de fazer este processo, para sempre que entrar nunca ter que efectuar login?

Comment: O que eu faria: Guarda o usuario e a senha do cara que logou em cookie e quando ele for logar, vê se possui o session, caso nao possua, você o cria

Comment: Não me parece muito fiavel.
Imaginemos que entro no PC de outro utilizador, vejo quais as credencias dele, depois basta copiar os cookies para o meu PC e acedo sempre à conta dele, sem realmente saber a password.

Comment: salvar um código secreto aleatório num cookie persistente após o primeiro login, salvando também o hash desse cookie no seu banco de dados. Se um usuário acessar o site sem estar logado, mas tiver um código válido, então considera-se que é o mesmo usuário voltando ao site e você o autentica automaticamente. Veja em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/85566/op%C3%A7%C3%A3o-manter-conectado-lembre-me-em-telas-de-login

Answer (score 0):

Sessions sempre que você fechar o browser ela será encerrada. Se você deseja algo mais duradouro use Cookies, você pode configurar quanto tempo ele fica disponível, mesmo fechando o navegador. Veja mais sobre cookies em:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.cookies.php